# Custom post type archive - error in nav-menu-template.php

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-post-type-archives

I created a custom post type called 'vehicle' using the [CCTM plugin](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/&ei=TNJCUq2aMIqv4AS8p4CACw&usg=AFQjCNEIs1c70yI-9G14-ERxecgyI0xSmQ&sig2=kQ7vw5FxNHWLlJXjm7KbAg&bvm=bv.53077864,d.bGE) and copy/pasted archive.php to archive-vehicle.php but this has resulted in an error in my header:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/.../public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 439
```

I get the same error repeated for every main menu item (there are no submenus).

If I remove archive-vehicle.php and view the same posts using archive.php no errors appear.

Why would this be?

**Update**

Line 439 of nav-menu-template.php is

```
in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $queried_object->ancestors )
```

`print_r($queried_object)` right before line 439 generates the following - there's no 'ancestors' key:

```
stdClass Object ( [labels] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Vehicles [singular_name] => Vehicle [add_new] => Add New [add_new_item] => Add New Vehicle [edit_item] => Edit Vehicle [new_item] => New Vehicle [view_item] => View Vehicle [search_items] => Search Vehicles [not_found] => No Vehicles Found [not_found_in_trash] => No Vehicles found in Trash [parent_item_colon] => Operator [all_items] => Vehicles [menu_name] => Vehicles [name_admin_bar] => Vehicle ) [description] => Each vehicle is linked to an Operator [publicly_queryable] => 1 [exclude_from_search] => [capability_type] => post [map_meta_cap] => 1 [_builtin] => [_edit_link] => post.php?post=%d [hierarchical] => 1 [public] => 1 [rewrite] => Array ( [slug] => vehicle [with_front] => 1 [pages] => 1 [feeds] => 1 [ep_mask] => 1 ) [has_archive] => 1 [query_var] => [register_meta_box_cb] => [taxonomies] => Array ( [0] => category [1] => features [2] => colours [3] => drivers ) [show_ui] => 1 [menu_position] => [menu_icon] => [can_export] => 1 [show_in_nav_menus] => 1 [show_in_menu] => 1 [show_in_admin_bar] => 1 [delete_with_user] => [cctm_hierarchical_custom] => 1 [cctm_hierarchical_includes_drafts] => [cctm_hierarchical_post_types] => Array ( [0] => operator ) [cctm_custom_columns_enabled] => 0 [post_type] => vehicle [use_default_menu_icon] => 1 [label] => Vehicles [cctm_show_in_menu] => 1 [cctm_show_in_menu_custom] => [rewrite_with_front] => 1 [permalink_action] => /%postname%/ [rewrite_slug] => [include_in_search] => 1 [include_in_rss] => 1 [cctm_enable_right_now] => 1 [custom_order] => ASC [is_active] => 1 [custom_fields] => Array ( [0] => passenger_capacity [1] => luggage_capacity [2] => hourly_rate [3] => included_milleage [4] => additional_mileage_price [5] => additional_image ) [map_field_metabox] => Array ( [passenger_capacity] => cctm_vehicledetails [luggage_capacity] => cctm_vehicledetails [hourly_rate] => cctm_vehicledetails [included_milleage] => cctm_vehicledetails [additional_mileage_price] => cctm_vehicledetails [additional_image] => cctm_default ) [original_post_type_name] => vehicle [name] => vehicle [cap] => stdClass Object ( [edit_post] => edit_post [read_post] => read_post [delete_post] => delete_post [edit_posts] => edit_posts [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_posts [publish_posts] => publish_posts [read_private_posts] => read_private_posts [read] => read [delete_posts] => delete_posts [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_posts [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_posts [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_posts [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_posts [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_posts [create_posts] => edit_posts ) ) stdClass Object ( [labels] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Vehicles [singular_name] => Vehicle [add_new] => Add New [add_new_item] => Add New Vehicle [edit_item] => Edit Vehicle [new_item] => New Vehicle [view_item] => View Vehicle [search_items] => Search Vehicles [not_found] => No Vehicles Found [not_found_in_trash] => No Vehicles found in Trash [parent_item_colon] => Operator [all_items] => Vehicles [menu_name] => Vehicles [name_admin_bar] => Vehicle ) [description] => Each vehicle is linked to an Operator [publicly_queryable] => 1 [exclude_from_search] => [capability_type] => post [map_meta_cap] => 1 [_builtin] => [_edit_link] => post.php?post=%d [hierarchical] => 1 [public] => 1 [rewrite] => Array ( [slug] => vehicle [with_front] => 1 [pages] => 1 [feeds] => 1 [ep_mask] => 1 ) [has_archive] => 1 [query_var] => [register_meta_box_cb] => [taxonomies] => Array ( [0] => category [1] => features [2] => colours [3] => drivers ) [show_ui] => 1 [menu_position] => [menu_icon] => [can_export] => 1 [show_in_nav_menus] => 1 [show_in_menu] => 1 [show_in_admin_bar] => 1 [delete_with_user] => [cctm_hierarchical_custom] => 1 [cctm_hierarchical_includes_drafts] => [cctm_hierarchical_post_types] => Array ( [0] => operator ) [cctm_custom_columns_enabled] => 0 [post_type] => vehicle [use_default_menu_icon] => 1 [label] => Vehicles [cctm_show_in_menu] => 1 [cctm_show_in_menu_custom] => [rewrite_with_front] => 1 [permalink_action] => /%postname%/ [rewrite_slug] => [include_in_search] => 1 [include_in_rss] => 1 [cctm_enable_right_now] => 1 [custom_order] => ASC [is_active] => 1 [custom_fields] => Array ( [0] => passenger_capacity [1] => luggage_capacity [2] => hourly_rate [3] => included_milleage [4] => additional_mileage_price [5] => additional_image ) [map_field_metabox] => Array ( [passenger_capacity] => cctm_vehicledetails [luggage_capacity] => cctm_vehicledetails [hourly_rate] => cctm_vehicledetails [included_milleage] => cctm_vehicledetails [additional_mileage_price] => cctm_vehicledetails [additional_image] => cctm_default ) [original_post_type_name] => vehicle [name] => vehicle [cap] => stdClass Object ( [edit_post] => edit_post [read_post] => read_post [delete_post] => delete_post [edit_posts] => edit_posts [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_posts [publish_posts] => publish_posts [read_private_posts] => read_private_posts [read] => read [delete_posts] => delete_posts [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_posts [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_posts [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_posts [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_posts [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_posts [create_posts] => edit_posts ) )
```

**Update 2**

archive-vehicle.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div id="content" role="main">

<?php
    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
     * what date we're dealing with (if that is the case).
     *
     * We reset this later so we can run the loop
     * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
     */
    if ( have_posts() )
        the_post();
?>

            <h1 class="page-title">
<?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date() ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyten' ) ) ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyten' ) ) ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
                <?php _e( 'Blog Archives', 'twentyten' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            </h1>

<?php
    /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
     * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
     * we can run the loop properly, in full.
     */
    rewind_posts();

    /* Run the loop for the archives page to output the posts.
     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
     * called loop-archive.php and that will be used instead.
     */
     get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' );
?>

                </div><!-- #content -->
            </div><!-- .col-md-8 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">      
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div><!-- .col-md-3 -->

            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .container -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Update 3**

wp-content\plugins\custom-content-type-manager\controllers\create_post_type.php:

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create a new post type.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if ( ! defined('CCTM_PATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
if (!current_user_can('administrator')) exit('Admins only.');
require_once(CCTM_PATH.'/includes/CCTM_PostTypeDef.php');

$data=array();
$data['page_title'] = __('Create Custom Content Type', CCTM_TXTDOMAIN);
$data['help'] = 'http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/wiki/CreatePostType';
$data['msg'] = '';
$data['menu'] = sprintf('<a href="'.get_admin_url(false,'admin.php').'?page=cctm" title="%s" class="button">%s</a>', __('Cancel'), __('Cancel'));
$data['edit_warning'] = ''; // only used when you edit a post_type, not delete.

// Variables for our template

$fields   = '';

$data['action_name']  = 'custom_content_type_mgr_create_new_content_type';
$data['nonce_name']  = 'custom_content_type_mgr_create_new_content_type_nonce';
$data['submit']   = __('Create New Content Type', CCTM_TXTDOMAIN);
$data['action'] = 'create';

$data['post_type'] = ''; // as default
$data['def'] = self::$default_post_type_def;
//      $def = self::$post_type_form_definition;

// Save data if it was properly submitted
if ( !empty($_POST) && check_admin_referer($data['action_name'], $data['nonce_name']) ) {
    $sanitized_vals = CCTM_PostTypeDef::sanitize_post_type_def($_POST);
    $error_msg      = CCTM_PostTypeDef::post_type_name_has_errors($sanitized_vals, true);

    if ( empty($error_msg) ) {
        // Clean slate.  This nukes any instance of 'is_foreign' (and potentially other issues)
        // that may arise if the post-type name was used by another plugin and the CCTM tracked
        // custom fields for that plugin, and then later the other plugin was deactivated and 
        // the CCTM wants to use the same post-type name.
        unset(CCTM::$data['post_type_defs'][ $sanitized_vals['post_type'] ]);
        CCTM_PostTypeDef::save_post_type_settings($sanitized_vals);

        $data['msg'] = CCTM::format_msg( sprintf(__('The content type %s has been created', CCTM_TXTDOMAIN), '<em>'.$sanitized_vals['post_type'].'</em>'));
        self::set_flash($data['msg']);
        include CCTM_PATH . '/controllers/list_post_types.php';
        return;
    }
    else {
        // clean up... menu labels in particular can get gunked up. :(
        $data['def']  = $sanitized_vals;
        $data['def']['labels']['singular_name'] = '';
        $data['def']['label'] = '';
        $data['msg'] = CCTM::format_error_msg($error_msg);
    }
}
$data['icons'] = CCTM_PostTypeDef::get_post_type_icons();
$data['columns'] = CCTM_PostTypeDef::get_columns($post_type);
$data['orderby_options'] = CCTM_PostTypeDef::get_orderby_options($post_type);
$data['content'] = CCTM::load_view('post_type.php', $data);
print CCTM::load_view('templates/default.php', $data);
/*EOF*/
```

wp-content\plugins\custom-content-type-manager\includes\CCTM.php register_custom_post_types function:

```
public static function register_custom_post_types() {
//return;
    $post_type_defs = self::get_post_type_defs();

    foreach ($post_type_defs as $post_type => $def) {
        $def = self::_prepare_post_type_def($def);

        if ( isset($def['is_active'])
            && !empty($def['is_active'])
            && !in_array($post_type, self::$built_in_post_types)
            && isset($def['post_type'])
            ) {
            register_post_type( $post_type, $def );
        }
    }
    // Added per issue 50
    // http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/issues/detail?id=50
    if (self::get_setting('flush_permalink_rules')){
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code where it generates error on line 439. It seems in_array() parameter 2 is not an array. Actually in_array require 2nd parameter to be an array.

Comment: @RahilWazir I've added line 439 as suggested - I should point out that nav-menu-template.php is a WP core file

Comment: @gpcola You're using the PHP function `in_array()` which only works for checking if a string exists in an ARRAY. You are attempting to check if your string exists in an OBJECT, using the `in_array()` PHP function. That is why you are receiving that error. Parameter 2 of `in_array()` must be an ARRAY.

Comment: Post of the contents of your `archive-vehicle.php`. Specifically any parts what call `wp_nav_menu` or related functions.

Comment: @MichaelEcklund - nav-menu-template.php is a WP core file so I have no control over it.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy - I'll add the content of my archive-vehicle.php above BUT remember that its identical to archive.php which doesn't product these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> print_r($queried_object) right before line 439 generates the following - there's no 'ancestors' key:

When you are on a post type archive calling `get_queried_object` (which the code probably does) or using `WP_Query::$queried_object` return the post type "object". All that is is the arguments with which the post type was registered.

The relevant bit of `nav-menu-template.php` in WordPress 3.6.

```
<?php
function _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( &$menu_items ) {
    // ...
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $parent_item ) {
        // ...
        if (
            isset( $parent_item->type ) &&
            (
                // ancestral post object
                (
                    'post_type' == $parent_item->type &&
                    ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $queried_object->ancestors ) &&
                    $parent_item->object != $queried_object->ID
                ) ||

                // ancestral term
                (
                    'taxonomy' == $parent_item->type &&
                    isset( $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    (
                        ! isset( $queried_object->term_id ) ||
                        $parent_item->object_id != $queried_object->term_id
                    )
                )
            )
        ) {
            $classes[] = empty( $queried_object->taxonomy ) ? 'current-' . $queried_object->post_type . '-ancestor' : 'current-' . $queried_object->taxonomy . '-ancestor';
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This bit `! empty( $queried_object->post_type )` should evaluate to false on post type archives. Something is adding post type to the queried object. And by something [I mean your plugin](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/custom-content-type-manager/trunk/includes/CCTM.php) which is `_doing_it_wrong`. Take a look at `CCTM::register_custom_post_types()` and `CCTM::$default_post_type_def`.

Anything that get's passed into `register_post_type` is just stored as an argument in the post type globals array.

If I do this:

```
register_post_type('some_type', array('this_is_not_a_wp_arg' => true));
```

On `archive-some_type.php` I can check for `this_is_not_a_wp_arg`.

```
<?php
// archive-some_type.php
var_dump(get_queried_object()->this_is_not_a_wp_arg); // true
```

Because your plugin happens to put `post_type` into the arguments array, it causes WP to evaluate `! empty( $queried_object->post_type )` as true. This isn't an issue in `archive.php` because `$query_object->post_type` is empty. As it should be on any post type archive. Unfortunately the CCTM plugin author doesn't understand the consequences of passing a "reserved" word like `post_type` as an argument key. This is why prefixing things is important.

**EDIT**

A very hackish fix is to hook into `init` very late and loop through all the post types. If the `post_type` argument is set, remove it. This may break other things the plugin does in the admin area.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse115604_fix', 10000);
function wpse115604_fix()
{
   foreach (get_post_types(array(), 'objects') as $type) {
       if (isset($type->post_type)) {
           unset($type->post_type);
       }
   }
}
```

This would prevent you from having to edit the plugin itself. I would do the above, then report the issue to the plugin author. If/when it gets fixed in a future version, you'll be able to remove that code.

**TL;DR:** CCTM adds a key to registered post types named `post_type` is messes with the order of things and sets a sequence of errors in motion.

Comment: Chris I've added the contents of wp-content\plugins\custom-content-type-manager\controllers\create_post_type.php above - note line 25 which reads `$data['post_type'] = ''; // as default` - isn't that suggesting that the `$queried_object->post_type` ought to be empty?

Comment: I also dug out the `register_custom_post_types()` function from `wp-content\plugins\custom-content-type-manager\includes\CCTM.php`

Comment: Assuming this problem relates to the fact that `post_type` exists in the arguments array - how should I remove that key?  If I edit `create_post_type.php` and comment out line 25 that would stop it from being added in future but what about my existing posts - how do I fix them? I hope I've understood what you said in your answer!

Comment: Gave you a possible solution in an edit just now. I would try to avoid editing the plugin itself.

Comment: Chris I really appreciate your efforts here - that hack worked in-so-much as I no longer see errors in the header.  I will post on `http://wordpress.org/support/forum/plugins-and-hacks`, linking to this question and hopefully the CCTM author will get around to solving this in a future update...